# relation between convergence and norms of sub-vectors in the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Assume we have a sequence $\mathbf{x}_{n} \in l_{2}$, where $l_{2}$ is a space of square-summable sequences. Then, consider the following statements

**Statement A:** $\mathbf{x}_{n}\to \mathbf{c}  \in l_{2}$ ,i.e. the sequence $\mathbf{x}_{n}$ converges in $l_{2}$ and

**Statement B:** For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n_{0}$ and $K$ such that for all $n > n_{0}$ we have  $\sup_{n>n_{0}} \sum_{k>K} x_{n,k}^{2} < \varepsilon$

What is the relation between statements?

If **Statement A** then **Statement B** or

**Statement A** iff **Statement B**

Comment: To me this looks related to the Cauchy criterion for convergence. Did you try writing it down explicitly in this context? Further statement A does not depend on $\varepsilon$, so I guess $B\Rightarrow A$ is definitely not correct in the present form.

Comment: @humanStampedist , I changes

Comment: If **A** is supposed to be just "$\mathbf x_n$ converges in $\ell_2$", then you need add "$\exists \mathbf c$" to the start. As it is, it is a demand that $\mathbf x_n$ converges to a specific sequence $\mathbf c$, which is not mentioned in **B**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify the notation a little bit. Let $\mathbf x = (\mathbf x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$. So it is $\mathbf x$ that is a sequence in $\ell_2$. For each $n, \mathbf x_n$ is an element of $\ell_2$, that is, it is $\mathbf x_n = (x_{n,k})_{k \in \Bbb N}$, a sequence in $\Bbb R$.

Being in $\ell_2$ each $\mathbf x_n$ is square-summable. That is, for each $n$, there is some real $s < \infty$ such that $s = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x_{n,k}^2$. Or:

> For every $n \in \Bbb N$, and every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $K > 0$ such that for all $K' \ge K$, $$\left|s_n - \sum_{k=0}^{K'}x_{n,k}^2\right| < \varepsilon$$

But $s_n - \sum_{k=0}^{K'}x_{n,k}^2 = \sum_{k>K'} x_{n,k}^2 \ge 0$, so the inequality can be rewritten as $$\sum_{k>K'} x_{n,k}^2 < \varepsilon$$
But also, since everything is positive, if it is true for $K' = K$, it will also be true for any higher $K'$, hence being square-summable is equivalent to

> For every $n \in \Bbb N$ and for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $K$ such that $\sum_{k>K} x_{n,k}^2 < \varepsilon$

Now, as stated every $n$ can have a different $K$. If you demand that the same $K$ holds for every $n$:

> For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $K$ such that for every $n \in \Bbb N, 
> \sum_{k>K} x_{n,k}^2 < \varepsilon$

This says that the $\mathbf x_n$ are *uniformly square-summable* with respect to $n$.

At this point we are very close to your statement **B**. The only difference (other than a trivial index variance) being your only requiring $K$ to work for all $n$ above some $n_0$. But that condition serves no purpose. because if a particular $K'$ works for all $n > n_0$, then so do all $K > K'$. And for each $n \le n_0, \mathbf x_n$ is also square summable, so there is some $K_n$ that works for it. Picking the max of $K'$ and all the $K_n$ for $n \le n_0$ gives a $K$ which works for all $n$.

So **B** is the condition that the $\mathbf x_n$ are uniformly square-summable. It should be clear at this point that it isn't directly related to convergence of $\mathbf x$ in $\ell_2$. Both **A** and **B** can hold without the other holding.

Letting $\mathbf x_n =((-1)^n)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ give an example of **B** holding when **A** does not. Counter-examples going the other way are more problematic to construct, and I'm out of time. Maybe later.